# FIWARE Lab NGSI HTTP proxy is available?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

We are having problems receiving notifications from Orion Context Provider. Our current environment is Wirecloud hosted in Fiware Lab and a custom instance of the Orion (v 0.24)

Test using **https://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org** as proxy:

Using this url, we get a subscription id, but we do not get any notifications when creating or updating entities. We read in other links this is due to Orion lacks capability to send notifications over https protocol and we need to install Rush.

Test using **http://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org** as proxy:

In the documentation of [ngsi-operators](https://github.com/wirecloud-fiware/ngsi-source-operator) says that we can use the http version if we run our own instance of the broker. But using this URL we cannot get even the subscription ID.

My questions: is there any problem with the HTTP proxy, is it still available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the same instance of the NGSI proxy for serving it through HTTP and HTTPS. It's very strange if you find that the HTTPS version is working and the HTTP version is not. Also, our Nagios instance (private at this moment, sorry) didn't report any issue with the NGSI proxy these days.

Probably, if you tried to use the http version of the NGSI proxy, you had problems mixing content coming from http and https. Firefox and Chrome show a "shield" icon on the address bar, and you must acknowledge insecure content for it to work. E.g.:

[image: Firefox insecure content alert]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://support.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/gallery/images/2015-02-20-11-15-34-219003.png))</sub>

If you want to know if you can connect to a concrete NGSI proxy instance, you can make a simple test by accessing it directly using a browser or using curl. E.g.:

`curl -v http://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org`

should produce the following log:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org/
*   Trying 130.206.81.241...
* Connected to ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org (130.206.81.241) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Date: Thu, 15 Oct 2015 10:13:28 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
* Connection #0 to host ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org left intact
Cannot GET /
```

As you can see, we don't have a pretty welcome page, but this 404 error code works for knowing that the NGSI proxy is alive.

Comment: Finally, I ended installing Rush and all work as expected. The solution you suggest, enabling insecure content, I tried it but didn't work. On the other hand, I noticed wirecloud NGSI api is not up to date for supporting new Orion types (v. 0.24): eg. geo:point. Receiving a geo:point property, application should receive "some-property: {type: geo:point, value: "whatever"}, but I get "some-property": "whatever". I guess you are working or planning to upgrade the api. Meanwhile I did a workaround in client for get over it :) thanks!